# Permutation of a sequence of integers where partial sum never reaches given values

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

I have been trying to figure out this problem, but to no avail. I have two input arrays: a[n] and b[n-1]. What I am trying to do is to output a permutation of the array "a" such that no partial sum is equal to any element in array "b". I'll try to illustrate this with an example:

a = {1, 3, 7}

b = {4, 8}

So, in this case, the permutation {1, 3, 7} wouldn't work because we have the partial sums:

1, 1 + 3 = 4 (which is part of array b), 1 + 3 + 7 = 11.

A good permutation would be {3, 7, 1}, because we have the partial sums:

3, 3 + 7 = 10, 3 + 7 + 1 = 11 (the results aren't in array b).

I have tried a dynamic programming approach (mainly subset sum problem), but it doesn't seem to be of use in this case. Does anybody have any idea how to approach this problem?

Comment: Would you need all possible permutations that meet this criteria - or just one permutation?

Comment: @Assafs Just one permutation would be enough.

Comment: Is a brute-force solution ok for you, or you want something else ?

Comment: @SchiduLuca I forgot to mention it, but I would like something else. A brute-force solution wouldn't be that hard to implement, but I can't seem to find a solution that is more efficient (maybe a dynamic programming approach or something)

Comment: @cosmin, it was fun working on this - I think I have a nice algorithm to get your answer (see below). If it works for you and looks OK in terms of efficiency, would you consider accepting it by clicking on the gray check mark, making it green? an upvote would also be great. I'm always available for comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm I suggest is recursive, and I also have a code sample that could be useful. The idea is to go in reverse:

First see if the total sum of array `a` doesn't appear in array `b` (if it is, we stop there).

Once we cleared the sum check, we need to decide the order of the elements. We start from the end, selecting a candidate `i` for the last position, and see if we can repeat this process for the n-1 array `a`, in which we removed our candidate from the array. If we do, we add the candidate `i` to the end position of the returned array - and return that array back.

The recursive steps are:

1. Given an array, check if it contains only one element. If so, check if the element exists in the forbidden sum array, If it is, return null. If it is not, return the array with its single element as-is. **(End Case)**
2. Given the array with more than one element:

   2.1. check its sum against the forbidden sum array. If it exists there, return null. if it does not, iterate over the array and for each element `i` call the method recursively with the array without candidate `i`.

   2.2. If the recursive call brought back null - continue iterating on.

   2.3. If it brought back an array, attach element `i` to the end of the array and return it.

The code below shows the algorithm in Java. I tried to keep it simple.

```
public static boolean contains(int[] arr, int val) {

    for (int i : arr) {
      if (i == val) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public static int sum(int[] arr) {

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i : arr) {
      sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
  }

  public static int[] removeElem(int index, int[] arr) {

    int[] retArr = new int[arr.length - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
      retArr[i] = arr[i];
    }
    for (int i = index + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
      retArr[i - 1] = arr[i];
    }
    return retArr;
  }

  public static int[] getArr(int[] arr, int[] forbidden) {

    if (arr.length == 1) {
      if (!contains(forbidden, arr[0]))
        return arr;
      else
        return null;
    }
    else {
      if (contains(forbidden, sum(arr))) {
        return null;
      }
      else {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          int[] retArr = getArr(removeElem(i, arr), forbidden);
          if (retArr != null) {
            int[] newArr = new int[arr.length];
            for (int j = 0; j < retArr.length; j++) {
              newArr[j] = retArr[j];
            }
            newArr[newArr.length - 1] = arr[i];
            return newArr;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int[] a = { 1, 3, 7, 9 };
    int[] b = { 4, 19, 16 };

    System.out.println("input array a: " + Arrays.toString(a));
    System.out.println("forbidden sum array b: " + Arrays.toString(b));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getArr(a, b)));
  }
```

Output:

```
input array a: [1, 3, 7, 9]
forbidden sum array b: [4, 19, 16]
[9, 1, 7, 3]
```

a few more examples:

```
input array a: [1, 3, 7, 9]
forbidden sum array b: [4, 19, 8]
[9, 7, 1, 3]

input array a: [1, 3, 7, 9]
forbidden sum array b: [4, 10, 8]
[9, 7, 3, 1]

input array a: [1, 3, 7, 9]
forbidden sum array b: [4, 10, 20]
null 
(for impossible forbidden sum)
```

Comment: Well done! I also gave a thought, trying to check if linear was possible but sooner or later, I ended up with a recursion as well :)